# Работа с планировщиком заданий Windows

Tags: c#, windows

Добрый вечер, столкнулся с такой проблемой. Создаю задание в планировщике задач.

```
 using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
 {
     TaskDefinition td = ts.NewTask();
     td.Triggers.Add(new LogonTrigger {Delay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)});
     td.Actions.Add(new ExecAction(this.Context.Parameters["path"], null, null));
     td.Principal.RunLevel = TaskRunLevel.Highest;
     ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition("CRMRun", td, TaskCreation.CreateOrUpdate, Environment.UserName, null, TaskLogonType.ServiceAccount);
 }
```

Только вот при создании задачи в планировщике, задание использует учетную запись "СИСТЕМА" и из-за этого задача не запускается. Если вместо `Enviroment.UserName` я пишу "User", то всё в порядке.
Использование `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name`вместо `Enviroment.UserName` приводит к такой же ошибке.
Так вот как же мне запихнуть туда "User" другими инструментами/методами?